# Console result in view

Tags: objective-c

Hi
I am calling a web service in objective c,and i am receiving the xml response in the console.
The problem is that i am not able to take data from xml to my view.
The response is a list,and each item has 4 elements
Any help

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: If you want to parse the element's of the xml you  might want to look in a parser library tutorial like NSXMLarser, if you want to show the ixm on view just save it to a NSString and show it

Comment: How are you storing this response? If you show us some of the code, it would certainly help...

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the XML response.  In OS X there are two approaches to this.

The first is to use [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  This is an example of a SAX parser.  It treats the XML as a stream and runs through it, sending callback messages to a delegate whenever it finds something interesting e.g. the start / end of an element or data within an element.

The second is [NSXMLDocument](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  This treats the XML as a document.  The XML is loaded all in one go and you get a tree of XML nodes that reflect the structure and data of your XML.

NSXMLDocument is easier to work with but requires much more memory than NSXMLParser.  It's also not available on iOS.